# Удаление элементов в списке словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dict

Всем привет, подскажите как можно удалить пару значений в списке словарей? Знаю про метод del dict_name[key] но он удаляет ключи со значением. Есть ли аналог чтобы удалить значение?
Есть одно решение, поменять местами ключи со значениями и удалить их но думаю это не правильно.

```
list_1 = [{'Name': 280, 'less': 'PIP'},
 {'Name': 6, 'less': 'Ticket in process'},
 {'Name': 7, 'dess': 'Defected'},
 {'Name': 8, 'dess': 'Need confirmation'},
 {'Name': 9, 'dess': 'Need remove'}]
```

Удаляем например ключ со значением 6 и 8 (может быть и больше) ....

```
result = [{'Name': 280, 'less': 'PIP'},
     {'Name': 7, 'dess': 'Defected'},
     {'Name': 9, 'dess': 'Need remove'}]
```

Comment: В чем проблема идти циклом по списку и делать del по каждому элементу списка?

Comment: @Сергей плоховой совет.... изменять то, по чему итерируешься

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше будет создать новый список и добавлять элементы, которые подходят, чем изменять существующий. Есть такие предложения:

1. Используем цикл `for`:

```
exc = [6, 8] # те, что вам не нужны
res = []
for el in list_1:
    if el['Name'] not in exc:
        res.append(el)
```

2. Используем функцию `filter`:

```
exc = [6, 8]
res = list(filter(lambda x: x['Name'] not in exc, list_1))
```

3. Используем генератор списка:

```
exc = [6, 8]
res = [x for x in list_1 if x['Name'] not in exc]
```

Comment: не дешевле по памяти будет сначала выбрать индексы, которые удалить, как у Вас и рассматривается, а потом из списка просто удалить эти индексы?

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков думаю вы правы. но сомневаюсь, что объемы данных у автора будет достаточно велики, чтобы была выгода от такого решения.

Comment: просто у Вас в каждом из примеров уже подразумевается, что индексы ненужных элементов выбраны. Можно пройти списку индексов от бОльшего к меньшему и удалить эти элементы из исходного списка. Хотя у автора исходный и результирующий списки вроде разные переменные, поэтому, может быть, я и не прав, если исходный список не должен меняться.

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков *подразумевается, что индексы ненужных элементов выбраны* это вы про список `exc` ?

Comment: да, именно про него. Всё, понял, это не список индексов, а список значений, которые не нужны. Был не прав.

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков это не индексы элементов. а значения ключей `Name`, от которых автор хочет избавиться.