# Удаление части списка

Tags: python

Я хочу удалить участок списка,а точнее все элементы с начала списка, пока я не наткнусь на присутствие '

' в обьекте списка, но у меня не выходит:

```
j=['123','321','hhh','awdawdawd</p>','s','ggg']
for i in range(len(j)-1):
    if '</p>' in j[i]:
        j.pop(i)
        break
    j.pop(i)
print(j)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Удаление элементов в списке словарей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1431148/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Comment: Нет, как я понял там есть конкретные элементы, которые не нужны, а мне нужно останавливать цикл, если есть в тексте </p>, например a,b,c,d,e</p>,g - мне нужно удалить все, кроме g

Comment: разумеется, там не абсолютно тот же пример, но почему, по-вашему, у вас не выходит?

Comment: У меня всегда разный список и </p> идет в перемешку с текстом.

Comment: Покажите, какой должен быть результат для вашего примера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно еще так сделать

```
for i in range(len(j)):
    if '</p>' in j[i]:
        j = j[i+1:]
        break
```

Т.е. при нахождении нужных символов в элементе, просто обрезаем начало исходного списка до элемента, следующего за текущим, и прерываем цикл, т.к. условие поиска выполнено. И не нужно использовать дополнительный список.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать такой подход, но только в случае, если гарантируется наличие элемента, содержащего `</p>`:

```
j=['123','321','hhh','awdawdawd</p>','s','ggg']
while '</p>' not in j[0]:
    j.pop(0)
j.pop(0)
```